# Getting the destination port of incoming UDP packet

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, c++11, udp

I've read through the ip man page along with the socket man page, all I could find was the destination IP address within the `IP_PKTINFO` control message in the header, there seems to be no way of pulling the destination port from the packet's header.  Or is there?

If not, is there any way to get the port from the socket a packet has arrived to?

Comment: Are you talking about raw socket? Normal UDP socket binds to a address and port.

Comment: No not a raw socket, yes it is bound to ip/port within a threadpool binding to many ports.  Also using boost.

Comment: I am using boost_socket.native() to access headers etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a normal socket, you can use recvfrom on the socket fd. The man page of recvfrom:

> RECV(2)
>
> NAME
>
> ```
>    recv, recvfrom, recvmsg - receive a message from a socket
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS

```
        #include <sys/types.h>
        #include <sys/socket.h>

        ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);

        ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                         struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);

        ssize_t recvmsg(int sockfd, struct msghdr *msg, int flags);
```

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    The  recv(),  recvfrom(),  and recvmsg() calls are used to receive messages from a socket.  They
>    may be used to receive data on both connectionless and connection-oriented sockets.
> ```
>
> recvfrom()
>          recvfrom() places the received message into the buffer buf.  The caller must specify the size of
>          the buffer in len.
>
> ```
>    If src_addr is not NULL, and the underlying protocol provides the source address of the message,
>    that source address is placed in the buffer pointed to by src_addr.  In this case, addrlen is  a
>    value-result  argument.   Before  the  call,  it should be initialized to the size of the buffer
>    associated with src_addr.  Upon return, addrlen is updated to contain the  actual  size  of  the
>    source  address.  The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this
>    case, addrlen will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.
>
>    If the caller is not interested in the source address, src_addr and addrlen should be  specified
>    as NULL.
> ```

An example from beej's guide:

```
// datagram sockets and recvfrom()

struct addrinfo hints, *res;
int sockfd;
int byte_count;
socklen_t fromlen;
struct sockaddr_storage addr;
char buf[512];
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

// get host info, make socket, bind it to port 4950
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
getaddrinfo(NULL, "4950", &hints, &res);
sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

// no need to accept(), just recvfrom():

fromlen = sizeof addr;
byte_count = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0, &addr, &fromlen);

printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n", byte_count);
printf("from IP address %s\n",
    inet_ntop(addr.ss_family,
        addr.ss_family == AF_INET?
            ((struct sockadd_in *)&addr)->sin_addr:
            ((struct sockadd_in6 *)&addr)->sin6_addr,
        ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
```

[Example of recvfrom](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/recvman.html), [man page of recvfrom](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/recvfrom.3p.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'm using `recvfrom` and `recvmsg` for multiple reasons already.  However, `sin_addr` and `sin_port` of the `sockadd_in` struct hold the source IP and port, not the destination.  Anyway, I got around my problem by using `boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(true);` to set the `SO_REUSE` flag allowing the same port to be used by multiple sockets.  However I'm still stumped as to why the destination port is not easily accessible on an incoming packet... it must be there somewhere.

Comment: When you are creating a normal socket, then you should have specified the port and ip while binding that socket, so you already know the port at which the messages which arrive(since you set it at time of binding the socket). Can you explain your situation in more detail ?

Comment: This is true, but we could say the same for the destination IP and it's available in the `msghdr`.  Our threadpool design means we may run the risk of not being able to correctly match the port with it's corresponding incoming packet, reading the packets header would be a much safer way.